# getting error while including $cordovaSocialSharing in the controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have created a hybrid app using ionic. I'm using the plugin cordovaSocialShare of NgCordova to make sharing on social networks in my application. I install the plugin by

> cordova plugin add [Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git)

command, but when I including it in my controller like the following

```
.controller('galleryCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaSocialSharing, GetStudentIdService, GetStudentPhotosService, GetStudentDetailService, $ionicModal, $rootScope)
```

It is giving me the folloing error message while ionic serve

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaSocialSharingProvider <- $cordovaSocialSharing <- galleryCtrl
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=ordovaSocialSharingProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaSocialSharing%20%3C-%20galleryCtrl

but If I remove `$cordovaSocialSharing` from the controller then It is working fine.

Please advise as to how I can fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have included ng-cordova.js . if yes then go to that file and look for $cordovaSocialSharing .

Comment: thanks @Creator for your concern. this 2 things I have done.

Comment: So you mean , you have injected ngCordova to your ionic app and then $cordovaSocialSharing is injected to controller and found in ngcordova.js . If yes , is this your first ng-cordova plugin in this app or have you included some other plugins too . Are they working fine ?. Oops too many question as this is dependency injection issue .

Comment: I have found the bug. I din't include ngCordova in my main module. So after including ngCordova as a dependency in my module it started working.

Comment: The thing is that First I haven't injected ngCordova in my app. that  was the main problem. thanks @Creator.

Comment: Ok i am adding it as an answer than. You can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add ngCordova to your ionic app dependency injection .

```
var app =  angular.module('ionic',['ngCordova']);
```

Comment: I am getting `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova`. Do I have to add **ng-cordova.js** to my index? I can not find that file.

Comment: @kamayd yes you need to add this file to your index file . download or get it from bower and include to index.html .

Comment: After running `bower install` I was able to get the file and added to the index